# Add + before word, see all between quotes as one word

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a question. I need to add a `+` before every word and see all between quotes as one word.

A have this code

```
preg_replace("/\w+/", '+\0', $string);
```

which results in this

`+test +demo "+bla +bla2`"

But I need
`+test +demo +"bla bla2`"

Can someone help me :)
And is it possible to not add a + if there is already one? So you don't get `++test`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you only want to try do it as a single preg-replace or is a multiline function appropriate?

Comment: It will be a function so multiline is fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this regex:

```
$string = '+test demo between "double quotes" and between \'single quotes\' test';
$result = preg_replace('/\b(?<!\+)\w+|["|\'].+?["|\']/', '+$0', $string);
var_dump($result);
```

// which will result in:

```
string '+test +demo +between +"double quotes" +and +between +'single quotes' +test' (length=74)
```

I've used a 'negative lookbehind' to check for the '+'.
[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this but could you try it and let me know how it goes?

First the regex: choose from either, a series of letters which may or may not be preceded by a '+', or, a quotation, followed by any number of letters or spaces, which may be preceded by a '+' followed by a quotation.

I would hope this matches all your examples.

We then get all the matches of the regex in your string, store them in the variable "$matches" which is an array. We then loop through this array testing if there is a '+' as the first character. If there is, do nothing, otherwise add one.

We then implode the array into a string, separating the elements by a space.

Note: I believe     $matches in created when given as a parameter to preg_match.

```
$regex = '/[((\+)?[a-zA-z]+)(\"(\+)?[a-zA-Z ]+\")]/';

preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

foreach($matches as $match)
{
    if(substr($match, 0, 1) != "+") $match = "+" + $match;
}

$result = implode($matches, " ");
```

Comment: Thanks but I am going to use @the fourth bird's code